# Unable to target lower versions of android in Virtual device Creation

Tags: android

Why i not able to target lower versions of android while creating virtual devices.
 I have installed the SDK of every version of android.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try close both SDK manager and AVD and re open. Also try close eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. this worked. but why could not it load the other versions.

Comment: It may be just that you just installed it with AVD open already and will only recognize it when its restarted. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your SDK manager, IF you had all earlier versions installed. If not then download them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

**Window => Android SDK Manager => Select API which you need** and Install it...........

hope this will help you...................